# When you update a set, which is a value in a map, and then put the key and value in the map, does it create a duplicate?

Tags: java, hashmap, set, hashset

For example, I have this code:

```
public void addDocument(DocumentId documentId, Reader reader) throws IOException {
        String s = "";
        List<String> list;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
        while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            list = Arrays.asList(s.toLowerCase().split("\\W+"));
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
            {
                if(!map.containsKey(list.get(i)))
                {
                    Set<DocumentId> newset = new HashSet<>();
                    newset.add(documentId);
                    map.put(list.get(i), newset);
                }
                else
                {
                    Set<DocumentId> set = map.get(list.get(i));
                    set.add(documentId);
                    map.put(list.get(i), set);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Does `map.put(list.get(i), set);` create a duplicate of the key and value in the map? If so, should I remove the pair before adding the updated list again?

P.S. The map is `Map<String, Set<DocumentId>>`

Comment: No, but actually in this case it is enough to modify (add the element to) the set (the second put is redundant).

Answer (score 1):

`Map` doesn't allow duplicate keys, the old value will be replaced for the key inside the `Map`, you can look at the API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)):

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map
>   (optional operation). If the map previously contained a mapping for
>   the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value. (A map m is
>   said to contain a mapping for a key k if and only if m.containsKey(k)
>   would return true.)

Answer (score 0):

> Does map.put(list.get(i), set); create a duplicate of the key and value in the map?

No, it doesn't. In Java, everything is a reference to an object, so, when you put the set in the map again, you're actually putting the same set as a value, mapped to the same key. Duplicate keys are not allowed (otherwise the structure wouldn't be a map).

You don't even need to put the set again in the map, as once you get the set and add an element to it, the set remains mapped to the key in the map.

You could achieve the same results by using the [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) method:

```
public void addDocument(DocumentId documentId, Reader reader) throws IOException {
    String s = "";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.toLowerCase().split("\\W+"));
        for (String word : list) {
            map.computeIfAbsent(word, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(documentId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this snippet instead of your conditional since you don't need to repeatedly add the set.  Creating the set and populating the map in a separate statement is cleaner and easier to maintain.

```
String key = list.get(i);
if(!map.containsKey(key)) {
    Set<DocumentId> newset = new HashSet<>();
    map.put(key, newset);
} 
map.get(key).add(documentId);
```